# Does Objective C & Swift support Hierarchical inheritance?

Tags: objective-c, swift, inheritance, multiple-inheritance

I know that Objective-C and Swift support multi-level inheritance. But do they support hierarchical inheritance too or is it that any language that supports multi-level inheritance supports hierarchical by default?

Comment: Both does not support direct multiple inheritance. But you can use protocol to achieve something similar but not exactly same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, both languages support hierarchical inheritance. There are countless examples in the iOS SDK.

UIResponder is subclassed by UIApplication, UIView, UIViewController.

UIView obviously has many subclasses as does UIViewController.

Answer (score 0):

The Wikipedia page about [Inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inheritance_(object-oriented_programming)) states that Java 8 supports Multiple Inheritance by [default methods](https://howtodoinjava.com/object-oriented/multiple-inheritance-in-java/).

Swift 4 Extensions support a very similar concept with [protocol extensions](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Protocols.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH25-ID521). So you can say that Swift 4 also supports multiple inheritance.